# IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, flask

I'm sending a file with the following route

```
@app.route('/file/')
@db_session
def file():
    filename = request.args.get('filename')
    response = make_response(filename)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp3'
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
    response.headers['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    response.headers["X-Accel-Redirect"] = '%s' % filename
    return send_file(
                 filename,
                 mimetype="audio/mp3",
                 as_attachment=True,
                 attachment_filename="%s" % filename)
```

It works fine in most desktop browsers and some mobile browsers.  But on others it does not, and I get this error

```
68.9.161.152 - - [13/Dec/2015 05:27:24] "GET /mp4/?filename=video/How_To_Shave_Your_Beard_Like_A_Man.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/www/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 653, in inner
    fd=fd).serve_forever()
  File "/home/www/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 505, in serve_forever
    HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 238, in serve_forever
    self._handle_request_noblock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 297, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.handle_error(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/www/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 217, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/www/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 252, in handle_one_request
    return self.run_wsgi()
  File "/home/www/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 194, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/www/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 185, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/home/www/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 166, in write
    self.wfile.write(data)
```

I've tried putting time.sleep(1) randomly in order to try and help.

Comment: Could be a problem with the content length. If you deliver the content as attachment it does not need to fit the actual file length. You should try without `Content-Disposition` and / or `Content-Length`.

Comment: Tried that, and it still does not work